# How to show that this limit does not exist? $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0, (x,y)\neq 0} \frac{x^3 y}{(x^4+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> I need to prove that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to 0, (x,y)\neq 0} \frac{x^3 y}{(x^4+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ does not exist.

For that, I try to take 2 converging sequences to $0$ with different limits when plugged into the function. I have tried all types of sequences (on lines, on a spiral, etc ...) but they all give a limit equal to $0$.

Can you give me any suggestion, please?

Comment: What did you get when you tried taking the limit along a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the path $\{(0,y):y \in R \}$ the limit is zero.

On the path $\{(x,x^2):x \in R\}$ the limit is non-zero as $x \to 0^+$

So the limit at $(0,0)$ does not exists.